# AlarmManager weird behavior when app is killed

Tags: android, kotlin

Im using AlarmManager to send a Notification every 10 min, and it works great when the app is in the background or running.

There is a button that activates the AlarmManager and the Broadcast Receiver.

The problem is that If i push the button and wait for the alarm to go off once and then kill the app, it will keep working and repeating the alarms but if i push the button and don't wait for the Alarm to go off one time, it won't work when the app is killed.

Why is this happening? is there a way to fix this?
Because i imagine people setting the alarm and maybe they want to clean resources or something and killing all the apps in their phone and not wait for it to trigger once.

Here the code for the AlarmManager in my Fragment:

```
 binding.button.setOnClickListener{
    val pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(requireActivity(), 0, intent, 0)
    val alarmManager: AlarmManager = requireActivity().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 60000, 600000, pendingIntent )  
}
```

Here is the Broadcast class:

```
class ReminderBroadcast: BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(context: Context?, p1: Intent?) {

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context!!, "postureNotification")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_notifications_24)
        .setContentTitle("Notification")
        .setContentText("Notification Text")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
        notify(100, builder.build())
    }
}
```

Here is the receiber in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".ReminderBroadcast"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these extra lines to you receiver in you manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".ReminderBroadcast"
    android:permission="TAKE_THIS_NOTIFICATION_RIGHT_NOW"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:process=":DontKillMyAlaramOrWhatever"
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TAKE_THIS_NOTIFICATION_RIGHT_NOW" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Also add this action to your intent:

```
myIntent.setAction("TAKE_THIS_NOTIFICATION_RIGHT_NOW")
```